# Android: Errors With R Only When Try To Compile

Tags: java, android

My app suddenly has come up with lots of errors when trying to compile and push onto my phone.
I get errors such as this one:

```
java: C:\Users\Steven\workspace\RandomGenie\src\com\frostbytedev\randomgenie\Menu.java:15: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable layout
location: class com.frostbytedev.randomgenie.R
```

The problem is in the source code there are no errors showing and nothing is underlined. What could be causing this and any quick fixes?

Comment: Remove the line `import com.frostbytedev.randomgenie.R` from any files that have it

Comment: No files have that line.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your XML files?

Answer (score 1):

check all your xml files in the res folder.... make sure there aren't any errors in them, when you make a change please ctrl+s then click project and select clean, check the build project as well.
also you could restart your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

If you try and compile or build your project while the `XML` file has errors your `R.java` file will not be created. Look in the gen folder and I can almost guarantee there is no `R.java` file. Search your `XML` files for an error. If you find that, post it or fix it then your app will compile and run again.